# asp.net mvc not deserializing entire child list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, deserialization

My ASP.NET MVC application is not deserializing the entire list back, but rather only 6 of the notes, given the abridged example below.  What might be the cause of this? On the page I'm seeing the correct number of results.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Notes() {
    var viewModel = new NotesViewModel();   
    viewModel.Notes = GetNotes(); // returns 50+ notes, displaying as expected
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Notes(NotesViewModel viewModel) {
  // viewModel.Notes only has 6 notes, but 50+ were passed to the view above
}

public class NotesViewModel {
  public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note {
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

<table>
@for (int i = 0;i < Model.Notes.Count;i++) {                                
    var note = Model.Notes[i];
    <tr>
        <td>@note.Id</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notes[i].Text)</td>                                                                                  
    </tr>
}     
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Comment: Doubt this would be the reason, but your an extra `</td>` in your loop. Also, out of curiosity, why are you using a `for`-loop and not `foreach`?

Comment: I'm using a for loop because that lets me have the indexes of each child element. I'll try again with foreach, but that's what I was originally using.  The </td> doesn't matter as you said.  I'll remove that.

Comment: It would also help if you show the rendered HTML

Comment: Is your POST function the same as your GET? What/how is the viewmodel being passed into it? (json/page post)? Can you show us those parts?

Comment: I solved this.  The reason this is happening is because there was a skipped number (on purpose) in the list of Id's which caused the iterator to stop looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. The reason this is happening is because there was a skipped number (on purpose) in the list of Id's which caused the iterator to stop looping.  You need the specific indexed list (foreach wouldn't work).

But I was conditionally skipping displaying items and that was putting a break in the continuity of the array indexes.